# How to dynamically add list items with id in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to fix a bug in the code below. I would like to add list items to 'ul' element while clicking the button. Now after looping it adds the last item every time the button is clicked. And another thing, How  to upload all three items "li" while clicking the button once? Thank you.

```js
let readId = [{id: 1, name: "John"}, {id: 2, name: "James"}, {id: 3, name: "Tom"}]
let ul = document.getElementById("root");

function createItems() {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < readId.length ; i++) {
   li.setAttribute("id", readId[i].id)
   li.innerHTML = readId[i].name;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createItems()">add item</button>
<ul id="root">
</ul>
```

Comment: If this is a task for college or tutorial that is fine. Otherwise use a framework like jquery, vue or angular

Comment: Move `let li = document.createElement("li");` into your loop

Answer (score 1):

Use a for each like this for better readability and I prefer using innerHTML property instead of createElement(), setAttribute...

```js
let readId = [{id: 1, name: "John"}, {id: 2, name: "James"}, {id: 3, name: "Tom"}],
  ul = document.getElementById("root");

function createItems() {
  readId.forEach(function(li) {
    ul.innerHTML += `<li id="${li.id}">${li.name}</>`;
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createItems()">add item</button>
<ul id="root">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `li` element for each name.

```js
let readId = [{id: 1, name: "John"}, {id: 2, name: "James"}, {id: 3, name: "Tom"}]
let ul = document.getElementById("root");

function createItems() {
  for (let i = 0; i < readId.length ; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id", readId[i].id)
    li.innerHTML = readId[i].name;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}

createItems();
```

```html
<ul id="root"></ul>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **3 li nodes**, so the first line in your function where you declare li must go into the for loop, on top of all.